# How to disable C++ error checking in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am producing C++ example code files, and as such they have a lot of inherent errors, e.g., made-up function names. I am trying to get rid of all error messages and error-related syntax highlighting in my files.

I imagine there is some setting for C++ but I could not find it.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message in the body of your question. Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51552414/edit) your question, and avoid to post comments to your own question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open up the **command palette** (CTRL + SHIFT + P) - > **C/Cpp: Toggle Error Squiggles**. This will disable all error warnings and highlighting.

Update: April 2020:
it is now called "c/c++: Disable Error Squiggles"

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's possible to disable specific files?

Answer (score 0):

This method will make the squiggly underline transparent.

***It will not remove error handling***,

Simply a *workaround* for annoying error and syntax highlighting with compiled languages.

---

Edit the json key value within the `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000"
    }
```

---